# angularjs evaluate template and set result to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a template that is rendered using [nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), a javascript templating engine. As I am already using angularjs, which has it's own templating engine, I would like to avoid an additional dependency and use angularjs for this template as well.

I understand how to template with angularjs to create a webpage.

In this case, I have a single xml file template that I would like to give inputs to and then get the result as a string.

I could make a directive with this template, insert it into the page, and then pull the contents of the element. This feels clumsy and messy.

Can I execute an angularjs template and get the result without having any modifications be done to the webpage?

Comment: use $compile(htmlTemplate)($scope)

Comment: @pixelbits Is $scope an object then? Is it required to include anything?